# Will an SSD help my machine's "snappiness"?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, ssd, speed

I have an IBM X31 (1.4Ghz, 1GB RAM, 320GB 5,400RPM HDD) running Windows 7. Would putting an SSD in it affect the "snappiness" of the machine? I'm not looking for raw power; I just want programs to open more quickly, Chrome to scroll more smoothly, freezing to occur less often, &c.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solid-State-Drives for Improved Performance](http://superuser.com/questions/216519/solid-state-drives-for-improved-performance) - or more exactly: [Should I get a Solid State Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/2347/should-i-get-a-solid-state-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's one major issue i see - [the X31 is a PATA based system](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X31)  - most SSDs are SATA based. You won't be able to use the more common SATA SSDs with it - there's very few PATA models and they're usually expensive enough that its not worth putting a . Even if there was PATA based SSDs, the interface would be a bottleneck.

IMO upgrading the ram would be a more worthwhile upgrade if possible - upgrading it to the maximum 2 gb it supports is likely to be a bigger improvement than upgrading it to SSD.

considering its age reverting it back to the stock XP, and putting the money for the SSD into a more modern system might even be an option worth exploring.

Comment: i mean this may well be me being naive but: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/2-5-SSD-IDE-16-GB-PATA-16GB-IBM-T40-T41-T42-Agp-/250603702103?pt=UK_Computing_HardDrives_RL&hash=item3a59250757#rpdId would that be compatible? the issue is whether there would be enough space for windows itself....

Comment: Yeah, thinkpads tend to have a lot of loyalty. I've used them for years (i said more, but idiotically deleted it ;p)

Comment: excellent I think I'll look in to that! yes i know...i just cant really bear to part with it...i have never liked any trackpad on a windows laptop so the red thing is the part id miss and theyre just so sturdy and well built! its getting a tad sluggish though...

Comment: no. windows 7 needs like..10 -20 on its own in my experience. MS says 16gb minimum - you'd be cutting it VERY close

Comment: @Sammy: I have an X31, and woudln't think of putting Windows 7 on it.  I wouldn't even do that with my X40.  But that SSD may be worth getting, as people have not been saying anything bad about them on the Unofficial ThinkPad forums - http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=76690

Comment: what OS would you reccomend XP? I cant really remember why I put 7 on...so if you think another OS would be speedier I'd be more than happy to give it a go!

Comment: @Sammy: XP SP3 works fine on an X31 and you already have a licence for XP Pro, that came with it.  You can use nLite to save some space, but an XP install is pretty small in comparison to Windows 7, anyway.  There is also vLite, which partially works with Windows 7, apparently. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLite_and_vLite

Comment: hmmm...I think I'll give XP a go! and at the moment I have a 320GB HDD in there so space isnt really a problem - i imagine I'm probably going to max out the RAM and see how it goes from there. Thanks for all the input guys! Sam

Comment: @Sammy: Yes, maxing it out to 2GB of RAM is the best way to speed up your X31.